# 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I moved my store from one server to another server and now the home page is opening but when I click on any link I am getting the below error

Not Found

The requested URL /dental-chairs.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Per This Link [The requested URL was not found on this server](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/) I am Check In Your Site And After Add `index.php` like this `vitalticks.in/index.php/create-your-package.html` open every category or page perfectly.

[image]